# Datagridview to Crystal Report in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

how do I pass the data from datagridview to crystal report viewer here's what I've tried:

```
        Dim rpt As New rptRadLogBook
        rpt.SetDataSource(dgvRequests.DataSource)

        frmLabReport.CRV1.ReportSource = rpt
        frmLabReport.ShowDialog()
        frmLabReport.Dispose()
```

: rptLogBook is the crystal report design
I get the error 'The report has no tables'

I have also tried using dataset and it had similar error:

```
    Dim q As String = "select * from LabExForm"
    Try
        If connL.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            connL.Close()
        End If
        cmd = New SqlCommand(q, connL)
        adptr = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dszx As New DataSet
        adptr.Fill(dszx)

        Dim rpt As New rptRadLogBook
        rpt.SetDataSource(dszx)

        frmLabReport.CRV1.ReportSource = rpt
        frmLabReport.ShowDialog()
        frmLabReport.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error sa printpreview " & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Finally
        If connL.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            connL.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: DataGridView don't (shouldn't) have data; perhaps put the data in a DataTable and send that to CR

Comment: @CaiusJard, I tried it already but I get the same error